# >> does not append in my For/if loop

Tags: bash, append

I am trying to get my bash script to create/append a file that states if the files have less or more than 150 errors. The problem is that I have 6 test files that have less than 150, and only one of those files are listed in error.log, instead of every file that matches it

I checked the list of files that the script uses for the y variable and it lists all of the files correctly.

```
set -x

for x in `ls -I import* -I pentaho* -I err*`
do
     unzip $x

ls | grep summary_report > summary.txt

            for y in `cat summary.txt`; do
                    if (( $(cat $y | awk 'FNR == 18 {print $3}') < 150 )); then
                     echo "$y has less than 150 Fatal Errors" >> error.log
                    elif (($(cat $y | awk 'FNR == 18 {print $3}') >= 150 )); then
                     echo "$y requires attention because it has more than 150 Errors" | tee error.log
                    fi
            done
    rm *.txt
done
```

Comment: You're saying that *`>>` does not append* but are you sure that leg of the `if` is being executed? It seems quite unlikely that `>>` isn't doing its job. Or it is appending, an then subsequently your `tee` is overwriting the file.

Comment: `tee --append` is what you want, I think

Comment: That worked. thanks!

Comment: Run your code through shellcheck.net. You are using `ls` improperly, and you are not correctly iterating over the contents of `summary.txt`.